# Inequality for Positive Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a open set. Consider the set $L^p(\Omega)_{+}=\left\{ f \in L^p(\Omega;\mathbb{R})\mid f\geq 0  \text{ a.e.} \right\}$. We say that a bounded linear operator $P:L^{p}(\Omega) \rightarrow L^{p}(\Omega)$ is positive if $PL^{p}(\Omega)_+ \subset L^{p}(\Omega)_+$.

It is well known that $|Pf| \leq P|f|$ for $f \in L^p(\Omega)$. I am trying to justify to myself that $(P f)^+ \leq  P(f^+)$ by modifying the proof used in proving $|Pf| \leq P|f|$. Just for clarity the proof for $|Pf| \leq P|f|$ uses the fact that $\operatorname{Re}(e^{i\theta}f) \leq |f|$ for $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$. I feel like I am missing something basic. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Does $L^p(\Omega)$ here mean a space of real-valued or complex-valued functions?  If real-valued, why are you talking about $e^{i\theta}$? If complex-valued, what does $f^+$ mean?

Comment: @nateEldredge I modified the question. The functions are real valued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $(Pf)^+ = (P(f^+ - f^-))^+ = ((P(f^+) - P(f^-))^+$.  Now observe that for any two nonnegative numbers $a,b$ we have $(a-b)^+ \le a$.

Comment: ahh perfection !